# What is Wrong in prepared statement Registration [NO Errors?]?

Tags: php, mysqli

SQL table consist of Id(AI),PID,AID,WEB,ADVERT

My code gets all variables but does not registers anything. But There are two methods of registration.

A. Form includes only to fill PID and Website, where ADVERT is sent hidden.

B. Form includes PID,AID,and website where Advert is sent hidden.

PID is not unique and can be multiple

AID is Unique or 0 if not registered selecting the FORM A in which AID is passed as 0 or NULL

Website is not unique and can be duplicate

If AID is null or 0

IF AID is NULL Check if PID and WEB match [Only Once registered if AID is null]

IF AID is Not NULL Check if AID,PID and WEB is already registered. [Already exist]

LASTLY If Everything is OKAY Register the product in database.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $u = $_SESSION['username']; //GETS Session username to register a product
    require('db.php'); //db connection
  //  ----------------PART A------------
    //This gets the ID index Number of user from Member Table 
    $user = "SELECT id from members WHERE username=?";
    $stmt = $ref->prepare($user);
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $u);
    $rc = $stmt->execute();
    if ( false===$rc ) {
      die('execute() failed at 1: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
    }
    $stmt->bind_result($ux);
    $stmt->fetch();
    $stmt->close();
     echo "Pass A <br>"; //Testing purpose
// ----------------------------------------------------------

    $aid = $_POST['proslot']; 
    $web = $_POST['web'];
    $pid = $_POST['pub'];
    $advert = $_POST['advert'];
//-------------INFO DEBUG-----------------
    //Testing  Codes Variables pass
    echo "<br>uid:<br>".$ux;   // User ID
    echo "<br>advert:<br>".$advert;  //Product advertiser
    echo "<br>pid:<br>".$pid;  //Product id
    echo "<br>aid:<br>".$aid;  //audit id
    echo "<br>web:<br>".$web;  //Product website
//------------------------------------------------------  
//-------------------PART B-----------------------------    
    if($_POST['adslot'] != NULL){

//Cheack if AID and WEBSITE matches any existing record.
    $valid = "SELECT id from prologger WHERE  aid=? AND userweb=?";
    $stmt = $ref->prepare($valid);
    $stmt->bind_param("is", $aid,$web); 
    $rc = $stmt->execute();
    if ( false===$rc ) {
      die('execute() failed at 2: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
    }
    $stmt->store_result();
    $val = $stmt->num_rows;
    if($val > 0){
        echo "Product Already exist :";
        $stmt->close();
        $ref->close();
        exit();
    } else{
        $stmt->close();
        $ref->close();
    }
        echo "Pass B[1]";
//---------------------PART B[2]-------------------------
 } else {       
        //Cheack if PID,AID and WEBSITE matches any existing record.
    $valid = "SELECT id from prologger WHERE pid=? AND aid=? AND userweb=?";
    $stmt = $ref->prepare($valid);
    $stmt->bind_param("sis", $pid, $aid,$web);
    if($_POST['adslot'] == '0' || $_POST['adslot'] == NULL) {
        $aid = '0' or $aid = NULL;
    } else {
        $aid = $_POST['proslot'];
    } 
    $rc = $stmt->execute();
    if ( false===$rc ) {
      die('execute() failed at 3: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
    }
    $stmt->store_result();
    $val2 = $stmt->num_rows;
    if($val2 > 0){
        echo "Unique product per website Required. This product is already registered to this website:"
        $stmt->close();
        $ref->close();
        exit();
    }
    $stmt->close();
//------------------------------------------------------ 
//------------------------PART C------------------------ 
    echo "Pass C";

    echo "<br>ROW 1:<br>".$val;  //DEBUG VALUE 

    $sql = "INSERT INTO prologger (uid,advert,pid,aid,userweb) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";
    $stmt = $ref->prepare($sql) ;
    $stmt->bind_param("sssis", $ux , $advert, $pid, $aid , $web); //bind variables
    if($_POST['adslot'] == NULL) {
        $aid = '0';
    } else {
        $aid = $_POST['adslot'];
    } 

    $input = $_POST['web'];

        $input = trim($input, '/');

        // If not have http:// or https:// then prepend it
        if (!preg_match('#^http(s)?://#', $input)) {
            $input = 'http://' . $input;
        }

        $urlParts = parse_url($input);

        // Remove www.
        $web = preg_replace('/^www\./', '', $urlParts['host']);

    $rc = $stmt->execute();
    if ( false===$rc ) {
      die('execute() failed: at 4 ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
    }
    $stmt->close();
    $ref->close();
        echo "Pass Final";
    }
    //------------------------------------------------------ 
    ?>
```

Comment: Can you also please add db.php file? It could be because of  $stmt->close(); in your codes.

Comment: `if(isset($ref)){
 $ref->close();
} else {

$host ="localhost";
$user ="admin";
$pass ="12345";
$dbname ="sysmtest";

$ref = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $dbname);
if(mysqli_connect_error()) { echo mysqli_connect_error(); exit();}
 
}`

Comment: Is it because i am closing `$ref->close();` in db.php? If thats the case O_O ohh my thanks to asked. I will try to remove that condition.

Comment: I remove the "if..else" condition inside db and tried it too somehow it does not goes beyond PASS B.

Comment: NVM I fixed it myself. There was an "IF else" Condition that was in this above code PART B  `if($_POST['adslot'] != NULL){ //code  } else { rest of the code }` where `Else` needed to be removed and a `$ref->close` in the B Part in the else statement `if($val>0)` condition. which needed to be removed. Thanks Anyways jameshwart :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it myself. There was an "IF else" Condition that was in this above code **Part B**

`if($_POST['adslot'] != NULL){ //code } else { rest of the code }`

where `Else` needed to be removed

and a `$ref->close` in the **Part B** in the `else` statement of `if($val>0)` condition which needed to be removed to fix the issue.